# MATLAB: Sliding colfilt problem with custom function

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm trying to do a custom Matlab function using `colfilt` where if the value of the pixel is black or white (0 or 255) the value will be the median of neighbours. Since I'm using `colfilt`, that means that the neighbours values are present in the same column and therefore I did this function:

```
function [Y] = Lab3_2(X)
    n = X(5)
    if(n ==255 || n ==0) 
       Y = median(X)
    else
       Y = n
    end
end
```

And the function gets called with:

```
Y = uint8(colfilt(Isp,[3 3],'sliding',@Lab3_2))
```

Where `Isp` is an image with salt&pepper noise.

The problem is that I get this error:

> Error using reshape To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
>
> Error in colfilt (line 182)
>                       reshape(feval(fun,x,params{:}),block(1),block(2));

I read the documentation and it says that the function must return a row vector containing a single value for each column in the temporary matrix.

I think i'm not doing this correctly (I'm refering to my output variable Y) and also I'm not sure if the line `n = X(5)` is correct.

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you had a loop iterating over each column of the input matrix `X` (or, if `colfilt` passed the columns to your function one by one), your approach would work. To implement the loop, you'd do something like this:

```
function [Y] = Lab3_2(X)
    num_cols = size(X,2);   % get number of columns in X
    Y = zeros(1,num_cols);  % preallocate row vector Y

    for c = 1:size(X,2);    % iterate over each column of X
        Xcol = X(c);
        n = Xcol(5)         % check whether center pixel is 0 or 255
                            % assumes a 3x3 neighborhood
        if(n ==255 || n ==0) 
            Y(c) = median(X)    % yes, replace with median of column values
        else
            Y(c) = n            % no, use original value
        end
    end
end
```

But looping over the columns is unnecessary when `median` and the comparison operators already work column-wise over the entire matrix. A more concise way to do the same thing would be:

```
function [Y] = Lab3_2(X)
    Y = X(5,:)                            % initialize Y to current pixel
    bw_indices = (Y == 255 | Y == 0);    % get indices of 0,255 values
    X_median = median(X);                 % take medians of all columns
    % replace 0,255 values with their corresponding medians
    Y(bw_indices) = X_median(bw_indices); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, your answers were really helpful. I tried with the second version but i still get the same error: Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in colfilt (line 182) reshape(feval(fun,x,params{:}),block(1),block(2)); It seems to happen when it deals with the output row vector.

Comment: I had to change the operator "||" for "|" but now works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool. I tested it on Octave and the logical operators behave differently there. I'll change it in the answer to the working MATLAB version.